# Add new character in between a string builder string

Tags: string, stringbuilder

I am building a new string using string builder. But now if want to add new characters in between already existing characters in the stringbuilder. How do i do it?

Example code:

```
StringBuilder sbr = new StringBuilder(" ");  
sbr.append(1);
sbr.append(" ");
sbr.append(2);
sbr.append(" ");
sbr.append("3");
sbr.append(" ");
```

Now the string looks like 1 2 3

I want to add a new string after the number two. Can anyone please guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to insert the character at position 3

```
sbr.insert(2, "<new charactor>");
```

Comment: Yes. That should be a character.